# npm list -g can't work when Nodejs is installed through nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Recently I re-installed Nodejs and npm through nvm. All things worked well except for the `npm list -g` command. When I used the command, the global package it showed is just npm itself:

[image]

But actually, I have installed other many global packages. I can find them in the folders:
[image]

Also, another thing that makes me confused is there are 2 Nodejs folders. One is:

[image]

The other is:

[image]

Is there anything wrong? How can I find the global packages by using `npm list -g` command?

Answer (score 0):

When you install a global package using npm that comes pre-installed with Node at version, let's say 12, when you upgrade your Node installation to a new version using nvm or you tell nvm to switch to using a different Node version, the global package that was installed when you were using Node 12 will not be invokable because this global package resides in the folder specific to Node 12, Node 13 or Node 10 doesn' have access to that global package, so when you switch to different Node version manually or through nvm, you have to install that global package again. Each Node version installed through npm resides in their own folder and anytime you do `npm i -g package`, this global package will be downloaded to the folder specific to the currently used Node version **only**

Comment: But I have only one Nodejs version. And it is the version I currently use. Why can't I still find the global packages?

Comment: Is it has something to do with the NODE_PATH environment virable? It seems I didn't clear it before installing Nodejs using nvm.

Comment: Can you do `nvm ls` or `nvm list` to see which version of Node is currently used? And also `nvm which version_currently_used` to see the path of the currently used Node. Pretty sure nvm installs Node in a different location from what you showed here, typically in `$HOME/.nvm`

Comment: The node I use is v16.6.2 and I only installed this version. What is `nvm which`? I can't use this command.

Comment: If you can't invoke `npm which`, you may want to try `nvm root`, you should be able to see a Node folder in the path output by `nvm root`

Comment: Yeah, look in there, you should see a folder for your Node installations

Comment: Yes. There is a v16.6.2 folder containg a Nodejs. But I can't find the node_global and node_cache folders in it. Sould I configure the environment variable?

Comment: I already basically explained why you can't find those in my answer